# Matplotlib imshow is ignoring cmap, vmin, vmax for ax.imshow subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, imshow, color-mapping

I am trying to make subplots of small images of data and I am finding it completely impossible to adjust the cmap/vmin/vmax for any of these images. No matter what I can't figure out how to change the colour map and the limits, I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong.

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awu0t.png)

[Image of incorrect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcjBg.png)

Cheers!!

Comment: You are using the colorbar in a funny way. Try to do something like: `im = axarr[0,0].imshow(...)` then `colorbar(im)`

Comment: Sweet! Fixed it completely :) thank you so much

Comment: Please only share code as text not images.

Comment: @R.C. You should post your solution as an answer rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the colorbar in a funny way. Try to do something like:

```
im = axarr[0,0].imshow(...)
```

followed by:

```
colorbar(im)
```

What it does, is to take the created image and build the colorbar on top of it.